# How to run a mongod instance

Tags: mongodb

I am a starter of `MongoDB`. According to the "Import Example" section of MongoDB 3.2 Manual, the prerequisite for importing data into the database is to have a running `mongod` instance. With limited background knowledge of `MongoDB`, I failed to fully understand this line of instruction. Could anyone please give me some explanation on how to run a `mongod` instance step by step in Mac Terminal? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are several steps to do start mongodb var `mongod`

- created the `./bin/data/db` directory storing mongodb data file.
- Start one terminal for `mongodb server`
- Go to `mongo/bin`, and execute this command

  ```
  ./mongod
  ```
- Start another terminal for `mongodb shell`
- Go to `mongo/bin`, and run

  ```
  ./mongo
  ```
- Now we can connect to mongodb now, more  command like `show dbs`, `show collections`, `use dbname`, For more commands in mongodb, refer to `db.help()`...